# AES encrypt in Swift similar to Android

Tags: ios, encryption, swift3

I need to perform plain AES encryption without any padding and without mentioning cipher mode in Swift.

Can someone throw some lights on it?

In Android, it is possible to import the default framework,

```
 import javax.crypto.Cipher;
```

And do basic encryption,

```
encrypt_ciper = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
decrypt_ciper =   Cipher.getInstance("AES");
text=Base64.encodeToString(encrypt_ciper.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I need similar thing to be done for iOS in Swift.

Comment: It is always best to explicitly specify options such as padding and mode, add them to the Java call, see [javax.crypto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). Without padding the data to be encrypted length must be an exact multiple of the block size, 16-bytes for AES.

Comment: And ECB mode is insecure.  You should ensure that your Java code is secure before you replicate it elsewhere.

Comment: See [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.